# How to pass a variable between functions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry for the long code, but I felt that it was important that I include what I was trying to accomplish. I am a beginner with Python and programming in general and I was trying to make a simple text-based adventure game. The game was working good at first until I added the encounter with the bees. I ran the program and I chose to run from the bear, so my hp should be at 40, which was displayed. However, when I chose to swat the bees, my hp should then be at 0 because 40(my current hp)-40=0. My hp is however is displayed at 60, as if the bear encounter never happened. Is there some way I can fix this or is this a limitation in Python?

```
from sys import exit
from time import sleep
import time

#Hp at start of game:
hp = 100

#The prompt for inputs
prompt = "> "

#Bear encounter
def bear(hp):
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "stand" in choice:
        print "The bear walks off, and you continue on your way"
    elif "run" in choice:
        print "..."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "The bear chases you and your face gets mauled."
        print "You barely make it out alive, however you have sustained serious damage"
        hp = hp-60
        currenthp(hp)
    elif "agressive" in choice:
        print "..."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "The bear sees you as a threat and attacks you."
        print "The bear nearly kills you and you are almost dead"
        hp = hp-90
        currenthp(hp)
    else:
        print "Well do something!"
        bear(hp)

#Bee encounter
def bee(hp):
    choice = raw_input(prompt)
    if "run" in choice:
        print "..."
        sleep(2)
        print "The bee flies away and you continue on your way."
        currenthp(hp)
    elif "swat" in choice:
        print "..."
        sleep(1)
        print "You succesfully kill the bee. Good Job!"
        sleep(1)
        print "Wait a minute"
        sleep(2)
        print "The bee you killed gives off pheremones, now there are hundreds of bees chasing you."
        print "The bees do some serious damage."
        hp = hp-40
        sleep(1)
        currenthp(hp)
    else:
        print "Well, do something."
        bee(hp)

#Function to display the current hp of the current player
def currenthp(hp):
    if hp < 100:
        print "Your hp is now at %d" % hp
    elif hp <= 0:
        dead()
    else:
        print "You are still healthy, good job!"

#Called when player dies
def dead():
    print "You sustained too much damage, and as a result have died."
    time.sleep(3)
    print "GAME OVER!"
    print "Would you like to play again?"
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "y" in choice:
        start_game()
    else:
        exit(0)

#Called to Start the Game, useful for restarting the program       
def start_game():
    print "Welcome to Survival 101"

#START OF GAME
start_game()
print "You start your regular trail."
print "It will be just a little different this time though ;)"

time.sleep(3)
print "You are walking along when suddenly."
time.sleep(1)
print "..."
time.sleep(2)

#Start of first encounter
print "Wild bear appears!."
print "What do you do?"
print "Stand your ground, Run away, be agressive in an attempt to scare the bear"

#first encounter
bear(hp)

#Start of second encounter
print "You continue walking and see a killer bee approaching you"
print "What do you do"
print "run away, swat the bee away"
bee(hp)
```

Comment: use return to pass variable to caller

Comment: As an aside... this looks like a really cool project for a kid. Are you interested in tutoring my 12 year old (for pay) helping him write a game like this?  (I know off topic, but Bernard doesn't have contact info on his page).

Comment: I am actually only an 8th grader, but trying to learn to code. I want to be a game programmer in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `hp` to functions and inside a function you are updating it, but you are not getting the updated value `hp` back from the function. You should specify `return hp` inside the function to return the updated value, and you can store (or update) the updated value in the function call - e.g., `hp = bear(hp)`.

Comment: This is correct. Why so many people make Python text adventure games?

Comment: @Elric, because they are interested in them, or like them or think they are fun??